# Can I ask a question on Improvements between versions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

SharePoint comes in different versions, shapes and forms, is configured differently and used in multiple ways. Still I have customers that ask me "What improvements have been made to SharePoint 2013?", which I have a hard time to answer out of the blue. I may not cover every topic, and I would really need the help from the community to ask such a question.

Still I know from the FAQ that *"[Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)"*. So I stand here reluctant to ask such a question and immediately mark it as a community question, because of the FAQ statement. Can I ask such a question without having it deleted or closed as NARQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that such questions already exist as CW, I would say it's certainly possible:

[What is new in SharePoint 2013 ?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44875/what-is-new-in-sharepoint-2013)

[What features have been lost in SharePoint 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49622/what-features-have-been-lost-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Yes but... we generally try to avoid these types of list/poll/discussion questions. This is definitely a grey area we have on the site but if the community wants it we can mark it as CW and move on. :)

Comment: As you may have seen in my discussion with Anders on that second question; since the number of feature changes are finite (rather than the seemingly infinite number of opinions a subjective question would prompt), it should be possible to create a single comprehensive answer. However, I agree it's unlikely to happen.

Comment: Yep, makes sense to me.